# How can I write widget for horizontal displaying multiple checkbox?

Tags: python, django, django-widget

I have a form with multiple checkbox. But they are vertical displaying by default. I want to display their horizontally. I need to create custom widget for this task. I found a default code of  `CheckboxSelectMultiple`

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py#L765

```
class CheckboxSelectMultiple(ChoiceWidget):
    allow_multiple_selected = True
    input_type = 'checkbox'
    template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/checkbox_select.html'
    option_template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/checkbox_option.html'

    def use_required_attribute(self, initial):
        # Don't use the 'required' attribute because browser validation would
        # require all checkboxes to be checked instead of at least one.
        return False

    def value_omitted_from_data(self, data, files, name):
        # HTML checkboxes don't appear in POST data if not checked, so it's
        # never known if the value is actually omitted.
        return False

    def id_for_label(self, id_, index=None):
        """"
        Don't include for="field_0" in <label> because clicking such a label
        would toggle the first checkbox.
        """
        if index is None:
            return ''
        return super().id_for_label(id_, index)
```

link to git with django widgets

https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets

I found also `bootstrap` form for horizontal displaying `multiple checkboxes`

```
{% for ... %}
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="materialInline{{ .id}}">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="materialInline{{ .id}}">{{ .title}}</label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But I don't know how to unite this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the correct thing. As you can see, the default `CheckboxSelectMultiple` uses these two templates:

```
template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/checkbox_select.html'
option_template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/checkbox_option.html'
```

So the only thing you need to do is subclass this with your own widget and change the templates to your liking:

```
class HorizontalCheckboxSelectMultiple(CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    template_name = 'my_app/widgets/checkbox_select.html'
    option_template_name = 'my_app/widgets/checkbox_option.html'
```

The `checkbox_select.html` template is actually the `multiple_input.html` template which just wraps the group of options (in the default case with a `<ul><li>...`). The `checkbox_option.html` template is actually the one to use for each option, where you can put the bootstrap code without the for loop.

You'll want to look at the `input.html` template as well which Django includes in the `checkbox_option.html` template to understand the various widget variables you can use (like `widget.name`, `widget.attrs.id` etc...).

Comment: I did this and just changed the innermost `<li>` tags into `<span>` and now it's a compact horizontal layout but each group (if there are any) will be on their own line.